# Numerical solutions of Gross-Pitaevskii equation

Tags: differential-equations

I am trying to solve the [Gross-Pitaevskii equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gross%E2%80%93Pitaevskii_equation) numerically and using [`NDSolve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NDSolve.html), but this seems to be a dead end. The problem is boundary and initial conditions that I can't find a way to determine it. What can I do? The equation is as follows:

```
I*D[y[x, t], t] + D[y[x, t], x, x] + 
  0.5*Exp[0.02*t]*Abs[y[x, t]]^2*y[x, t] == -0.0001*x^2*y[x, t]
```

The article that I am working on is giving the analytical answer, but I need the numerical one.

Comment: If you have a question on how to select a proper initial and boundary conditions, then it's better be asked on [Physics.SE](physics.stackexchange.com).

Comment: What initial and boundary conditions to choose depends on what solution you want.  A few sample solutions are given in [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gross%E2%80%93Pitaevskii_equation).  Consider starting with a free particle, then going to a soliton.  Those may give you the confidence and experience to solve your particular problem

Answer (score 0):

To solve nonlinear equations numerically, I think the split-step Fourier method is a highly mature algorithm, which you can find described in the book "Nonlinear Fiber Optics" (G. P. Agrawal).

Comment: That would be a great help if you send me link to check it or a name to buy.